# HTTP POST/GET request to PHP script and JSON response

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have pages that send POST/GET requests to PHP scripts on the server. All PHP scripts respond in JSON. Question is how to capture the JSON response at the client-side in JavaScript.

Example : when i submit the form register.html, i want to capture and manipulate (using Javascript) the JSON response returned from http://localhost/register.php.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make an AJAX request.  You can do this quite simply by using a library such as jquery. Or a little more difficultly just using javascript.

Using AJAX will change the current flow of your application though.
This follow example is using jquery

```
<form onSubmit="makeRequest(); return false;"></form>

function makeRequest() {
  $.post('register.php', formDataHereAsAnObject, function(response) {
     console.log(response) // this response is your json
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i could recommend http://www.json.org/js.html for a detailed description of using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you **submit** a form in the classic sense, you're out of luck. What you want is to load the JSON response from the server. To achieve this, there are a few possibilities

- Set the target of your form to an invisible iframe and do submit it, then take the JSON out of there via JS (old school)
- Start an AJAX request (via a framework or directly), that ends up having your data in a JS variable